# Why android4.0.3 emulator has a pad layout on 640x960 screen

Tags: android, emulation

i have compile android4.0.3 from source, i want run emulator with screen size is 640x960, but the emulator's layout is like a pad, the statusbar is on the bottom with the virtual menu, i want the emulator likes a normal phone layout, the statusbar is on the top, and the 3 virtual keys are on the bottom.

I have try the offical SDK, it emulator can run 640x960 on phone like layout.
Is there any suggestion? thanks

Comment: check your avd details lcd.density is 275~.

Answer (score -2):

I think you computer Screen is small, the emulator run with real pix as you set,,  you can set it as default,then will look like a phone

Comment: what you mean "set it as default"? My computer screen size is 1920x1080, are you mean i should set my computer screen size more bigger?  thanks!!

Comment: I am  not good at English,sorry,looks your computer screen is very good, when you creat a avd,you should seclect the skin is default.